# Receive number (smsto:) from intent

Tags: android, sms

How can I receive sms number when someone chooses to send sms from their address book?
Now I've got that and I can choose my app

```
<intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
</intent-filter>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why I'm doing now:

```
Uri intentUri = getIntent().getData();
String to = URLDecoder.decode(String.valueOf(intentUri).replace("smsto:", ""));
```

I know its not probably the best answer, but it does the job.

Please, let me know if you found another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

`Data` contains "scheme-specific part". You can get this part to extract number without manual parsing the `Data` object:

```
String scheme = intent.getData().getScheme();
if ("smsto".equals(scheme)) {
     String number = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
     // Do something with this number
}
```